# Is there a non-branching bitwise solution to determine the "odd one out of 3" number if two are equal, else the first one?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
int64_t foo(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t c){
    return a == b ? c : a == c ? b : a;
}
```

Is there any non-branching bitwise hack that implements the function above?

Comment: What's wrong with the above (other than being somewhat hard to read)?

Comment: Is there any reason for that? I would never use such things until and unless I have to write code for [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/).

Comment: Maybe `a ^ b ^ c`, provided that any two of the variables are guaranteed to be equal.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth mostly for curiosity, but I'd like to see if such a thing could speed up my program since 20% of it is executing that line.

Comment: @GOTO0 that isn't a guarantee I have but I love that solution. I'll think about it.

Comment: If GOTO0 answer isn't what you need, redefine your question. What is the "correct" result where all values are unique?

Comment: Also, for whoever edited, I didn't even notice that function is an "odd one out number". It function for an entirely different purpose. How could I not notice that!

Comment: @Amit why? My question is what it is, I just don't have the guarantee that two numbers will be identical. If `a != b != c`, the answer is `a`. (The procedure basically is a substitution of `a` for either `b` or `c`, if `a` is identical to one of those - if it isn't, it stays the same.)

Comment: I can write `return a==b || a==c ? a^b^c : a;`, though - that is already an improvement!

Comment: So it is wrong to define it as "odd one out".

Comment: Fair enough, I think I will rollback the edit, then. It wasn't me who write it.

Comment: `return a==b || a==c ? a^b^c : a;` has the same number of branches (2), but a more complex return value. It's not any clearer to read either. Why would you want that?

Comment: @Amit fair enough, but I feel this is closer from a non-branching solution. Maybe there is another bitwise operation that would recover `a` in case it was changed by mistake?

Comment: You might want to optimize the code and look at the assembly. Many processors have *conditional move* instructions that can be used to implement this code, so you may find that the compiler has already removed the branches for you.

Comment: I'm interested in a logical solution, though, so whenever I move this to a different architecture (GPU) I know it will not branch.

Comment: if (!(a-b) | !(a-c)) return a^b^c; else return a;

Comment: @haccks "non branching" is today's equivalent of "least number of characters"

Comment: @Viclib GPU have support for predication and select instructions. The compiler knows how to use those for if-then-else constructs with small bodies, or for ternary operators, resulting in branchless machine code. I would strongly suggest writing this code in a natural way for GPUs, instead of making it into an unreadable bit-twiddling construct.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 `(!(a-b) | !(a-c))` is identical to `a==b||a==c` for all `a`, `b`, `c`? That looks neat but I don't get it. Edit: oh, I get it. Cool.

Comment: @Viclib You could, although I strongly suspect the impact on application-level performance is negligible, meaning this is likely a micro-optimization not worth spending time on. Profiling will tell you.

Comment: Exactly, I will know from profiling. I'm willing to take the work, so, why not? :)

Comment: if (!(a-b) | !(a-c)) return a^b^c; else return a; only have one branch, return a==b || a==c ? a^b^c : a; have 2 without optimizing. but you may end up in UB if the reults have a integer underflow.

Comment: @Viclib In the worst case, such clever bit-twiddling transformations may make it *harder* for the compiler to optimize the code. Reducing the readability of code also contributes to long-term maintenance cost. Lastly, you may well be incurring opportunity cost, meaning you could be working on higher-value parts of the code design instead of twiddling this particular expression.

Comment: Don't worry, I know all that. The code is an automata consisting of 5 micro functions like that. I have a lot of time to try many possibilities on each one of those and see what works better. The code is so small and documented that such bitwise hack won't be an issue. It takes a comment to explain why it is there, what it does and even link to this SO question. I appreciate your concerns, though. That is important and a good attitude of your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, the are:

```
return ((!(a-b))*(c^a))^((!(a-c))*(b^a))^a;

if a=b=c: (1*(c^a))^(1*(b^a))^a = a^b^c= a

if a=b != c: then (1*(c^a))^0^a= c^a^a= c
```

the same for `a=c != b`

```
if a != b != c: (0*(a^c))^(0*(a^b))^a = 0^0^a=a
```

it is questionable if this way is faster, but try it.

**UB-Warning**.
if `a-b` or `a-c` result in a over or underflow, it is undefined behavior. may use unsigned variables.

Comment: @R.I.P. Seb only one line was code, the rest is a try of a explanation. so yes i am.

Comment: The OP needs to define "branching". Based on the C abstract machine, this use of `!` involves a branch. Based on common CPUs, it doesn't, but neither does the version with `?:`. I share your question: is there any implementation where your answer is really better performance wise?

Comment: @hvd you have a good point, but I'm just looking for alternate solutions so I can test them. I shouldn't phrase it as requesting for `non-branching`, but it is too late now.

Comment: @Viclib As a quick experiment, I compiled your original code and the suggested replacement above for the GPU with CUDA 7.5 (target architecture sm_35, e.g. Tesla K20). Both variants result in branchless code. The original straightforward code compiles to 8 instructions, the bit-twiddly code compiles to 16 instructions.

Comment: Point taken, @njuffa. It is still good to learn those things :)